# MySQL consequent numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I use this function in my while loop to track the numbers of results.

```
$lvarcontributor = "SELECT * FROM  dD_Contributors WHERE idAlbum = '".$idAlbum."' ORDER BY idContributor ASC";
$lvarresult=mysql_query($lvarcontributor);
$var = 0;
while ($lvarrow = mysql_fetch_array($lvarresult))
    {
    $var++;
//STUFF HERE...
}
```

How do I know the last result?
I need to know when $var++ is arrived at the last result. such as

```
If($var == "LAST RESULT") {
//do this
}
```

THANKS!

Comment: You know the last result right after the while-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql_num_rows function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: How that is going to help me? Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 0):

This function may be helpfull:

[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if (($var + 1) == musql_num_rows($result))
{
   //this is the last row
}
```

Comment: This is not giving the last result, but the one before the last result

Comment: well, yes, you're right, because you have $var++ just before the if expression. It's a good habit to always (when it is possible) place counter increments at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $var == mysql_num_rows($lvarresult) - 1 ) {
    // this is the last row, do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to check the [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function.
If you want to access only the last result, you should review your SQL query to fetch only this one (try messing with ORDER BY and LIMIT).

If you want to fetch every rows, but have a special treatment for the last result, then you can dut as follow:

```
$nextRow = mysql_fetch_array($lvarresult);
while ($nextRow)
{
   $currentRow = $nextRow;
   if($nextRow = mysql_fetch_array($lvarresult)) {
        //Not the last row, data in $currentRow
   }
   else {
        //Last row, data in $currentRow
   }
}
```